# Abstract Method / Avoid Casting

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I have this code :

```
public interface Position {
  public int getX();
  public int setX(int x);
  public int getY();
  public int setY(int y);
}

public StandardPosition implements Position {
  // STANDARD implementation of Position here
}

public abstract class Mover {
  public abstract Position move ( Position originalPosition ); 
}
```

A "Mover" is something that moves something from an initial position to a final position.

Now here's the interesting part ... some movers are more complicated and work with Position objects that are a bit more complicated.

```
public class ComplicatedPosition extends StandardPosition {
 // ADDS Y DIMENSION
 private int y; 
 public int getY() { return(y); }
 public void setY(int y) { this.y = y ; }
}


public class MoreComplicatedMover extends Mover {

  @Override
  public void Position move(Position initialPosition) {
    ComplicatedPosition q = (ComplicatedPosition) initialPosition; 
    // Do a transformation and 
    // return a new position
    return(q); 
  }

}
```

My question here is ...is there any way to avoid casting from the Position to ComplicatedPosition ...(we are casting from interface to class .. seems a bit awkward ) ... 
Another way of asking this question is : is there any other way to set up this code ?
Cheers !

Comment: You need to clarify some of your code examples. Are Position.setX() and Position.setY() supposed to not have arguments? Is ComplicatedPosition a class or interface? Only interfaces can extend other interfaces, but interfaces can't have implementation as shown in the example.

Comment: Thanks @Dev I just made edits ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well one thing you could do is use generics like:

```
public abstract class Mover<T extends Position> {
  public abstract T move(T originalPosition ); 
}

public class ComplicatedMover extends Mover<ComplicatedPosition> {
  public ComplicatedPosition move(ComplicatedPosition p) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

However I'm not sure if this is what you should want.

btw; is your `Mover` supposed to give a new Position or alter the given Position?
Personally I would make it a `void` method if you are altering the given Position.

Comment: Thanks .. to clarify : the Mover is supposed to give a new position ;-)

Comment: @MadSeb ah ok, I got thrown off because your `ComplicatedMover` returns q again ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the API for `ComplicatedPosition` is different with `StandardPosition` (which I assume it is and that is the reason why you are casting), update your `Position` interface and put all needed APIs in there. Then, first approach would be implementing those extra methods in `StandardPosition` and simply putting

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("");
```

A better approach is to implement adapter pattern and have an abstract class like `PositionAdapter` which implements all those extra methods and throws the `UnsupportedOperationException` and then have

```
public class StandardPosition extends PositionAdapter {
}
```

This way you won't have to implement a bunch of not needed methods in your `StandardPosition` or any other implementing classes. Then you can get rid of your castings and call all methods on interface.
Hope this helps.